# Is there a way to modify sizing for each letter in a text?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using this code to gradually increase and decrease my headline from the center. I thought there might be a more **CSS** or **JavaScript** approach to this. Does anybody have an idea?

```css
.logo {
  font-family: 'arial';
  color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <span style="font-size: 78px;">H</span><span style="font-size: 84px;">E</span>
  <span style="font-size: 88px;">L</span><span style="font-size: 90px;">L</span>
  <span style="font-size: 94px;">L</span><span style="font-size: 90px;">L</span>
  <span style="font-size: 88px;">O</span><span style="font-size: 84px;">O</span>
  <span style="font-size: 78px;">O</span>
</div>
```

Thanks much!

Comment: i think is a good approach.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49107252/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't advise to use JS here unless you absolutely need to. Even if you want to animate the text, use [css animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Here's a clean CSS example of what you're probably trying to acieve.

```css
.logo {
  font-family: 'arial';
  color: blue;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.logo > span:nth-child(1) { font-size:70%; }
.logo > span:nth-child(2) { font-size:80%; }
.logo > span:nth-child(3) { font-size:90%; }
/* .logo > span:nth-child(4) { font-size:100%; } */
/* .logo > span:nth-child(5) { font-size:100%; } */
.logo > span:nth-child(6) { font-size:90%; }
.logo > span:nth-child(7) { font-size:80%; }
.logo > span:nth-child(8) { font-size:70%; }
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <span>h</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>o</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree and think your approach is the best.

Answer (score 0):

SCSS allows you to use "for" sentence.
Here's an example of html and SCSS.
Please try writing at CodePen.
(If you don't intend to use SCSS, I'm sorry.)

```css
.logo {
  font-family: 'arial';
  color: blue;
  }

@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  .font-#{$i} {
    font-size: 78px + $i*4;
  }
}

@for $i from 5 through 9 {
  .font-#{$i} {
    font-size: 98px - ($i - 5)*4;
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="logo">
                <span
                class="font-1">H</span><span
                class="font-2">E</span><span
                class="font-3">L</span><span
                class="font-4">L</span><span
                class="font-5">L</span><span
                class="font-6">L</span><span
                class="font-7">O</span><span
                class="font-8">O</span><span
                class="font-9">O</span>
            </div>
```